# Do Jmeter support direct Import of Jmx file into azure devops

Tags: jmeter

Does defining like below one:

```
Host : ${__P(host,devops-url)}
```

In the user defined variable in testplan & run in non gui mode as:

```
  jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -Jhost=devops-url
```

Would solve the problem that jmx file would get import into devops repos  pipeline??

1. If so, how about devops credentials?
2. By defining anywhere in jmeter, Does JMeter anywhere support direct import of jmx into devops repos folder? Any supported jar is required?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your JMeter test into Azure DevOps and run it from there, see [Run Apache JMeter load tests with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=azure-devops) article for more details.

I don't think there is an existing way of triggering an Azure DevOps JMeter test from on-premise JMeter instance, the only option I can think of is triggering pre-defined existing JMeter test in Azure DevOps via [Azure DevOps Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) so basically from JMeter you send a HTTP Request which will kick off your test there.

There is also [BlazeMeter Azure DevOps Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004191957-Testing-via-Azure-DevOps-Pipeline-Testing-via-Azure-DevOps-Pipeline) but again it's not about starting test in Azure DevOps from your machine